# Terraform dynamically add VPC ID into Route53 Zone

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terraform0.12+

I'm going to make use of [this](https://registry.terraform.io/modules/terraform-aws-modules/route53/aws/latest) Terraform registry module to create the VPC private hosted zones.

I've defined my parent module variable just like below, So I can use variables depends on my workspace to pick the appropriate Zone attributes and it works pretty well.

Now what I want to do is, I want to add the **VPC_ID** into the resource block from my data source output (`data.aws_vpc.this.id`), so I can use the variable block like in `domain2.my`. The reason is, if I use the variable, I want to hardcode the VPC ID (`Just like in domain1.my`). So I need to avoid hardcoded VPC ID and able add the VPC ID dynamically from data source and also should be able to add additional VPC IDs just like shown in the `domain3.my`

Can anyone help to solve this problem? Thank you!

**variables.tf**

```html
variable "zone_name" {
  description = "Domain name of The Zone"
  default = {
    dev = {
      "domain1.my" = {
        comment = "DEV Private Hosted Zone"
        vpc = [
          {
            vpc_id = "xxxxx"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
    stg = {
      "domain2.my" = {
        comment = "STG Private Hosted Zone"
        vpc     = []
      }
    }
    uat = {
      "domain3.my" = {
        comment = "UAT Private Hosted Zone"
        vpc     = [
          {
            vpc_id = "VPC ID"
          },
          {
            vpc_id = "Another VPC ID"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
 }
```

**main.tf**

```html
#source = "../../../../tf-modules/aws/route53/zones/"
module "zones" {
  source  = "terraform-aws-modules/route53/aws//modules/zones"
  version = "~> 1.0"

  zones = var.zone_name[local.workspace]

  tags = {
    ManagedBy = "Terraform"
  }
}

data "aws_vpc" "this" {
  tags = {
    env = local.workspace
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you be more clear? Add vpc where? `terraform-aws-modules/route53/aws//modules/zones` does not take vpc_id as an input argument.

Comment: Thanks @Marcin for the quick response. Can you check this sample. So you will get what I mean.
https://github.com/terraform-aws-modules/terraform-aws-route53/blob/7686fffeb35e4b48592fc9bff717be9c4a5402a4/examples/complete/main.tf#L27